# Making a border zooming effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using JavaScript how can I make a border zooming effect?

[image]

Where the border of div1 expands to the size of div2. Ideally I want to attach the start of the effect to some event. And get a call back when the effect is completed. Also I want to be able to reverse this.

Comment: Do you have code we can help with?

Comment: http://synodins.com/guides/html5_missing_manual/css.html

Comment: Not really, I have 2 divs of different sizes.

Comment: So kinda like this http://jqueryui.com/addClass/ ?

Comment: @Hermann the problem with your example and say jQuery's zoom is that the same content is zoomed in. I'm looking for an effect to transition to a different div. This: http://highslide.com/examples/inline.html comes very close. But this framework is terrible

Comment: You might try searching for 'css animation' or 'jquery animation', trying some code out and coming back with exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: the difference between one div and another is just the characteristics that it has, so if you change its characteristics it might as well be called a different div. just thoughts.

Comment: The first div has some of the information that the second div has the second div is an editable widget. So I'd like the effect of opening a card (which becomes greyed out) and displaying a second div which only symbolically is the same as the first div

Comment: you can make a div, have it change to apparently become the same as the original and then disappear (by increasing zindex or turning width down to zero or div.removechild), creating the illusion that the first div morphed into the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i understand what you want, i think thats it:

```
var div1DefaultWidth = $('.div1').css('width');
var div1DefaultHeight = $('.div1').css('height');

var div2DefaultWidth = $('.div2').css('width');
var div2DefaultHeight = $('.div2').css('height');

$(document).on('mouseenter','.div1',function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'width':div2DefaultWidth,
        'height':div2DefaultHeight
    },{duration:250, complete:function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('.div2').show();
    }
    });
}).on('mouseleave','.div2',function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('.div1').show().stop().animate({
        'width':div1DefaultWidth,
        'height':div1DefaultHeight
    });
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y336m/2/

**UPDATED:**

if your elements have different `padding/margin/top/left` use this:

```
var div1DefaultWidth = $('.div1').css('width');
var div1DefaultHeight = $('.div1').css('height');
var div1DefaultTop = $('.div1').css('top');
var div1DefaultLeft = $('.div1').css('left');
var div1DefaultMargin = $('.div1').css('margin');
var div1DefaultPadding = $('.div1').css('padding');

var div2DefaultWidth = $('.div2').css('width');
var div2DefaultHeight = $('.div2').css('height');
var div2DefaultTop = $('.div2').css('top');
var div2DefaultLeft = $('.div2').css('left');
var div2DefaultMargin = $('.div2').css('margin');
var div2DefaultPadding = $('.div2').css('padding');

$(document).on('mouseenter','.div1',function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
        'width':div2DefaultWidth,
        'height':div2DefaultHeight,
        'top':div2DefaultTop,
        'left':div2DefaultLeft,
        'margin':div2DefaultMargin,
        'padding':div2DefaultPadding
    },{duration:250, complete:function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('.div2').show();
    }
    });
}).on('mouseleave','.div2',function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('.div1').show().stop().animate({
        'width':div1DefaultWidth,
        'height':div1DefaultHeight,
        'top':div1DefaultTop,
        'left':div1DefaultLeft,
        'margin':div1DefaultMargin,
        'padding':div1DefaultPadding
    });
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y336m/3/

Comment: Thanks that's pretty much what I was looking for. Here is my version of it: http://jsfiddle.net/Y336m/5/ thanks again!

Comment: Great job, you did great. even though i havent quite understood your explanation, im glad it have helped you. greetings